# How to detect if a certain library used in IOS app

Tags: kotlin, apk

I am working on a project where I create statistics on the third party libraries included in the mobile apps (both Android and IOS). When it comes to Android, things are easier since the resulting .apk file is a .zip file that I can extract and inspect the package, like the com folder. However, when it comes to IOS, it's not that easy. I am mainly interested in the IOS apps that a developed using Kotlin. Is there an easy way to check the third party libraries in IOS apps that were developed using Kotlin?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example for such an app?

Answer (score 1):

If macOS is your dev environment - look at nm, rpath, otool and install_name_tool. If **a.out** is your built target, start with -

`otool -L ./a.out`

`otool -tvV ./a.out`

`nm ./a.out`

In terms of libraries, I assume you mean shared libraries. In which case -

`otool -L ./a.out`